# Why isn't this function working?

Tags: python

Just trying to play around with some LPTHW functions. I made this up here:

```
def character_class(intel, str, agil):
    print "A barbarian's main attribute starts at: %d." % str
    print "A wizard's main attribute is intel, and it starts at: %d." % intel
    print "An archer's main attribute is agility, and has the default agility speed of: %d.\n" % agil


character_class(20, 40, 60)
print character_class

character_class(20 + 40, 40 + 50, 100 + 100)
print character_class

input1 = raw_input("Barbarian str:")
input2 = raw_input("Wizard intel:")
input3 = raw_input("Archer agil:")
character_class % (input1, input2, input3)
print character_class
```

And these are the results I'm getting in Powershell:

```
A barbarian's main attribute starts at: 40.
A wizard's main attribute is intel, and it starts at: 20.
An archer's main attribute is agility, and has the default agility speed of: 60.

<function character_class at 0x025078B0>
A barbarian's main attribute starts at: 90.
A wizard's main attribute is intel, and it starts at: 60.
An archer's main attribute is agility, and has the default agility speed of: 200.

<function character_class at 0x025078B0>
Barbarian str:200
Wizard intel:300
Archer agil:400
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test19.py", line 16, in <module>
    character_class % (input1, input2, input3)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'function' and 'tuple'
```

First of all, what is `<function character_class at 0x025078B0>` that is appearing after every call to the function `character_class`? This didn't appear during LPTHW exercise 19.

Also, I'm trying to get raw_input from the user, to insert into the function. Is this not possible, or am I doing it wrong?

Revision: Changed the last line of code to: `character_class(input1, input2, input3)`

And this is the error I get now:

```
A barbarian's main attribute starts at: 40.
    A wizard's main attribute is intel, and it starts at: 20.
    An archer's main attribute is agility, and has the default agility speed of: 60.

    A barbarian's main attribute starts at: 90.
    A wizard's main attribute is intel, and it starts at: 60.
    An archer's main attribute is agility, and has the default agility speed of: 200.

    Barbarian str:1000
    Wizard intel:2000
    Archer agil:3000
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test19.py", line 16, in <module>
        character_class(input1, input2, input3)
      File "test19.py", line 2, in character_class
        print "A barbarian's main attribute starts at: %d." % str
    TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Final revision:

```
def character_class(intel, str, agil):
    print "A barbarian's main attribute starts at: %d." % str
    print "A wizard's main attribute is intel, and it starts at: %d." % intel
    print "An archer's main attribute is agility, and has the default agility speed of: %d.\n" % agil


character_class(20, 40, 60)


character_class(20 + 40, 40 + 50, 100 + 100)


input1 = raw_input("Barbarian str:")
input2 = raw_input("Wizard intel:")
input3 = raw_input("Archer agil:")
inputa = int(input1)
inputb = int(input2)
inputc = int(input3)

character_class(inputa, inputb, inputc)
```

Comment: About the error: what are all the differences you notice between `character_class(20, 40, 60)` and `character_class % (input1, input2, input3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, lets look at your output:

```
A barbarian's main attribute starts at: 40.
A wizard's main attribute is intel, and it starts at: 20.
An archer's main attribute is agility, and has the default agility speed of: 60.

<function character_class at 0x025078B0>.
```

And then the code that generates this output:

```
character_class(20, 40, 60)
print character_class
```

You have defined the character_class function above to take three parameters and call the print function three separate times. When you call `character_class(20, 40, 60)`, you are passing in 20, 40 and 60 as your parameters. Your function will then call `print` three times, using a newline feed in the last call, resulting in the first four lines of your output shown.

When you call `print character_class`, you are passing in a function definition as a parameter to the print function. The output, `<function character_class at 0x025078B0>`, is the *reference location* of the defined function. The point being, you do not need to call `print` before your `character_class` call, as you have *defined* your function to call print three times. When python is executing `character_class(20,40,60)`, it will step into the function and execute each line of code you defined and insert the parameters you passed using string substitution. The additional `print character_class` is not necessary, as your function code does the `print`-ing for you.

Lastly, you are obtaining your raw input correctly. The `raw_input` function will take your input from the console and return the result, which you have assigned into a variable. Your call (`character_class % (input1, input2, input3)`) is almost correct, however I am thinking you are mixing up calling a function with string variable substitution.

You only need to call your function by passing the three parameters you obtained from input: `character_class(input1, input2, input3)` and your function will do the printing for you, as you have defined it to do above!

Comment: A very in-depth explanation. However, as I explain above, once I change that last line of code to: `character_class(input1, input2, input3)`, I'm prompted with yet another error message (shown above in an edit).

Comment: The last line of your error statement should help here: `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str`. It is stating that within your function definition of `character_class(input1, input2, input3)`, python is expecting a number but you gave it a string. When you are using string substitution, recall that you are specifying the *type* of what you want to substitute after the `%` character- which you specify with `%d`. This tells python to expect a digit to substitute in place of `%d`, however input1, input2 and input3 are all strings. This is because the raw_input() returns strings.

Comment: I understand now...I didn't immediately remember that raw_input only returned values as strings. Thank you for clarifying that. I did a final revision on my code in my post. While this does work, I feel like there's a shorter way to convert the values I get from raw_input() to int(), instead of making new variables. Or is the way I did it the shortest way?

Comment: Ignore the last comment; I found the shortest way to convert the string into an integer: 
`input1 = int(raw_input("Barbarian str:"))` Thanks for your input again!

Comment: Excellent. One last thing to note, your implementation requires the values that you enter to raw_input actually be an integer. Otherwise, you will get a type error trying to cast 'any letters' to an int! LPTHW is an excellent resource though! good luck

Answer (score 2):

You're successfully calling the function, which does the printing, and then each time you also tell Python to print the *function itself*, when you do `print character_class`. Just don't do that.

Also, I don't know why you've used `%` in the last one, where you're passing in the data from raw_input. Again, don't do that:

```
character_class(input1, input2, input3)
```

Comment: So I totally get the first half of your comment now (thanks for that btw). But the second half is...well, I understand what you're saying about adding in the % modifier (that it's not necessary). But I did it your way, and now I'm getting this error ( I added the new error in an edit in the post).

Answer (score -1):

I am not too knowledgeable in regards to unicode.  I believe it to be reference code for specific characters on a keyboard and what not.  Also, your problem was not too clear.  However, I wrote this, hopefully it somewhat reformats and answers a couple questions you had:

```
class character_class(object):
def __init__(self, intel, str, agil):
    self.intel = intel
    self.str = str
    self.agil = agil

def input(self):
    str = input1
    intel = input2
    agil = input3
    print "A barbarian's main attribute starts at: %r." % str
    print "A wizard's main attribute is intel, and it starts at: %r." % intel
    print "An archer's main attribute is agility, and has the default agility speed of: %r.\n" % agil
    cont = raw_input("")

input1 = raw_input("Barbarian str:")
input2 = raw_input("Wizard intel:")
input3 = raw_input("Archer agil:")
character_class = character_class(input1, input2, input3)
character_class.input()
```

I'm still rather new to programming, so my code might be a bit 'off' or sloppy or whatever.  Anyway, I assigned intel, str, and agil to a class property, and then defined those through raw input.

When you run this script, it will prompt you for the attributes under input 1-3, and then display them through character_class.input(). Those input values are assigned to str, intel, and agil.  Did this answer your question in any way?  If not let me know.